# Converting text file to xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, text, apache-camel, xslt-2.0

input.txt:

```
a|b|c|d|e|f|g
A|B|C|D|E|F|G
```

First line are tags and second line are values. How to convert this to xml using 'xslt' and apache camel.

output.xml:

```
<products>
    <product>
        <a>A</a>
        <b>B</b>
        <c>C</c>
        <d>D</d>
        <e>E</e>
        <f>F</f>
        <g>G</g>
    <product>
<products>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your processor supports XSLT 2.0, and you are supplying it with a dummy XML document, then you could do something like:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- path to text file -->
<xsl:param name="textfile">input.txt</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/"> 
    <xsl:variable name="lines" select="tokenize(unparsed-text($textfile), '&#10;')" />
    <xsl:variable name="names" select="tokenize($lines[1], '\|')" />
    <xsl:variable name="values" select="tokenize($lines[2], '\|')" />
    <products>
        <product>
            <xsl:for-each select="$names">
                <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
                <xsl:element name="{.}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$values[$i]"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </product>
    </products>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this will fail if any one of the tokens in the top line is not a valid XML element name.